# What is the idiomatic way to return ValidationErrors in fastapi middleware?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

I have a simple FastAPI middleware that checks whether the request contains a parameter called "job_id", and if so sets some state.

Code:

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def set_active_job(request: Request, call_next):
    if not request.url.path.startswith("/action"):
        return await call_next(request)

    body = await request.body()
    body = ActionModel.model_validate_json(body)

    if app.state.active_job is not None:
        return JSONResponse(
            status_code=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT, content=dict(status="busy")
        )

    app.state.active_job = body.job_id
    try:
        return await call_next(request)
    finally:
        app.state.active_job = None
```

However, right now if `model_validate_json` fails (throwing an exception)--Fast API returns a 500 error, when ideally it would return the output it normally returns when a request body fails to match a model.

How can I fix this?